# Simple band arithmetic on GDAL virtual rasters (VRT)

Tags: raster, gdal

I want to calculate the difference of two bands. I have the individual bands stored somewhere, but I was thinking that maybe there's a way of producing a VRT file that is the result of this difference. I know that you can use pixel functions in GDAL, but this limits the use (C++, and only available when the function is linked in...).

It would be nice if simple "virtual" operations were available!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily, yet...

There are a couple of ways around though. In C++ you can compile the pixel function then dynamically register it by using the GDAL plugin mechanism (there are some examples [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/3367)). Or even more interesting to Python scribblers like myself, you can write pixel functions in [Python](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/autotest/gcore/testnonboundtoswig.py?rev=22896#L172)!

Comment: OK, I wasn't aware that you could write python pixel functions. I guess that's as good as it gets :)

Comment: While theoretically you can write VRT pixel functions in Python, I imagine that would be rather inefficient.  I'd think you'd be better served letting more optimized code do the heavy lifting, i.e. use a GIS (qgis, ESRI, etc.) or numpy if you're writing scripts.