# Making virtual raster with average values

Tags: qgis, raster, ndvi

I'm working with many raster files. Is there a way to make virtual raster with average values in each pixel. (QGIS)

It's for an NDVI index of summer months over 5 years.

Comment: Not easily, but it can be done - http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/16798/2856